# Ionic slider + loop + click event issue

Tags: ionic2

I am using slider with dynamic data using property loop and autoplay
Button/Click does not work when going from last slide to first slide
slide next and slide previous both scenario.

**NOTE** - its working fine without loop property

for more details:  [forum link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-slider-loop-click-event-issue/97554)

thank you,